# Ionic datetime-local input breaks in iOS 14

Tags: angularjs, datetime, ionic-framework, input, ios14

Since the update of iOS14, datetime-local input fields on iphone are being rendered as text fields, allowing the user to input a string and preventing them from using the native datetime selector.

Is there any change on those fields with the latest update of iOS or is it a bug on their side?

**Previous behaviour(iOS 13):**

[image: Previous behaviour]

**Current behaviour(iOS 14):**

[image: Current behaviour]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No success so far @SantiagoVasquez , I think it might be an issue with Ionic 1 UiWebView. I've implemented a workarround with ng-material-datetimepicker while waiting for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this is fixed on iOS 14.6.